# How to remove the effect reflection of shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, shaders

In this image, why the shadow is strongly reflected on the person. How can I fix that problem ? I am using a direct lighting by setting  the rendering parameter as:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you limit the light path bounces?

Comment: enable ambient occlusion

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a .blend which shows this behavior?

Comment: the shadow is not reflected , just  there is no light bouncing of other objects

Comment: @Chebhou, How can I enable the ambient occlusion?

Comment: it is in the world tab

Comment: @Chebhou, it generates a lot of noise in function of distance.

Comment: @gandalf3, it difficult because it contains a lot of image texture

Comment: @Denis, yes, I am using a direct lighting method as mentioned in the first image

Comment: The light will not reach the areas that in opposite direction of the light, you need to add more light bounces, and for faster rendering I would suggest to use Blender Internal instead of cycles.

Comment: @Denis, thanks for your response. I am obligate to use cycles engine because as you remark,  i am using a fishe eye camera that is not enable in internal blender.

Comment: @startingBlender are you allowed to use some nodes ( material or composting ) ?

Comment: @Chebhou, yes, I am in cycles engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you appear to have one light source and no bounces/indirect lighting.
So the only faces to receive *any* light will have to be facing the light source.

In the real world light is reflected and transmitted everywhere, resulting in almost everything getting illuminated at least a little bit.

You have several options to simulate this:

- Increase the number of bounces in *Render settings > Light paths*, allowing light to reflect off surfaces and illuminate "around corners" in a physically correct fashion:

  [image]
- Enable ambient occlusion or add some ambient environment lighting:

  In the real world there is always ambient light coming from the sky. Even with indoor renders this can make a difference (light coming through windows etc.)

  [image]

  Note that AO is an approximation of actual environment light, but as it's all based on distance it will illuminate things even inside closed shapes where environment light cannot normally reach.
- Add more light sources with different sizes:

  If you still want to stick with 0 bounces and no [global illumination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_illumination), try adding a few more light sources. Vary the strength and size to prevent it from becoming too "flat":

  [image]